Rigorous definition of the matter power spectrum
I have been working with the concept of matter (or any 3D field) power spectrum for a while, but still struggle to understand it precisely. The power spectrum $P(k)$ is defined by the equation
$$
\left\langle \delta (\mathbf k)\delta^* (\mathbf k') \right\rangle
=(2\pi )^3 \delta_\text D(\mathbf k-\mathbf k')P(k),
$$
where
$$
\delta (\mathbf k)
=\int d^3 x e^{-i\mathbf k\cdot \mathbf x} \delta (\mathbf x).
$$
So, clearly $\delta (\mathbf k)$ is a complex number. However, when setting $\mathbf k=\mathbf k'$, we have
$$
\left\langle |\delta (\mathbf k)|^2 \right\rangle
=(2\pi )^3 \delta_\text D(0)P(k).
$$
How could the right side have a $\delta_\mathrm D(0)$ term when the left side is a real number?

I'm not sure why this is tagged as homework but I think it is a good, conceptual question.

This is confusing. Usually the $\delta$-function found in the first equation represents a Dirac $\delta$-function. However, the Fourier transform of a Dirac $\delta$-function is a constant and not another Dirac $\delta$-function on the Fourier domain. So what is going on here?

$\delta(\vec{x})$ is a random field. It is not a real number. The sample space from which $\delta(x)$ comes from is real-valued functions from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Meaning, if you were to draw one realization from the random process underlying $\delta(\vec{x})$, you would get a function, $f(\vec{x}$) (also known as a scalar field). Or, in other words, the probability distribution for $\mathbb{P}[\delta(\vec{x})]$, assigns a probability to every possible scalar field. (Well, technically a probability density with some function-space measure, but rigorously defining that gets a bit above my paygrade). One more way to say this is that the average $\langle \delta(\vec(x)\rangle$ is a real-valued function of space. But $\delta(\vec{x})$ itself is not.
You can trade $\delta(\vec{x})$ for $\delta(\vec{k})$ by doing a Fourier transform. Then $\delta(\vec{k})$ is a random field, and one realization of this field will be a complex function of $\vec{k}$. Because $\delta(\vec{x})$ was real, $\delta(\vec{k})$ will satisfy $\delta(\vec{k})^\star = \delta(-\vec{k})$. However, otherwise everything I said about $\delta(\vec{x})$ above applies to $\delta(\vec{k})$.
Now, the real point is that you have to be very careful to interpret a quantity like $P(k,k') = \langle \delta(\vec{k})\delta(\vec{k'})\rangle$. You might expect it to be a normal function of $\vec{k}$ and $\vec{k'}$, but you have to remember that $\delta(\vec{k})$ is a random field, which is an unusual mathematical object, so some kind of computation is needed to figure out what this two point function actually is -- the answer isn't obvious up front if you don't have experience. If you are careful, you will find that $P(k,k')$ is actually a distribution, not a function. This is a situation that pops up all the times in statistical physics. One non-rigorous way to phrase what is going on is that $\delta(k)$ actually represents an infinite number of "normal" random variables (one for every wavenumber $k$). The distribution is such that the densities at different points are not correlated, but the densities at the same point obviously are correlated. Because the correlation is localized at one point, for there to be nonzero variance if you integrate over a region, $P(k,k')$ must be infinite when $k=k'$. There are more rigorous and formal ways to explain this, but that is just to give some intuition. This distributional nature is captured by the delta function.
